# PHP insert text value in SQL server

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I am wanting to create a text box that would send whatever is typed to my database. However I am unsure where am I am going with what I have done so far as I am met with my fail message

> Error querying SQL Server database

Any help would be appreciated. I am also currently using SQL server as my database.

```
  <?php

  $serverName = "serverName"; 
  $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbname", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

  if( $conn ) {
       echo "Connection established.<br />";
  }else{
       echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
       die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }

  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please type the car you are using:</p>

<form action="StartScreen.php" method="post">
  <input type = "text" id = "carType" name ="carName">
  <input type="submit" id= "submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
<?php
  $carType=($_POST['carName']);

  if(isset($_POST['carName'])) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO carInfo(carType);
VALUES ($carType)";

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql)or die('Error querying MSSQL database');
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note: move `$carType=($_POST['carName']);` inside `if(isset($_POST['carName']))`. You can also drop those parentheses at assignment.

Comment: I'd also suggest parametrized queries rather than directly inserting the parameter into the query in order to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Also, use [`sqlsrv_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors) to get the exact error.

Comment: Is the `;` inside query string just a typo? If not then remove it.

Comment: @b.man  Your T-SQL statement is wrong. It should be al least `$sql = "INSERT INTO carInfo(carType) VALUES ('$carType')";`, but, please, use parameterized statements to prevent SQL injection attacks. `sqlsrv_query()` does both statement preparation and statement execution.